# Shell is variable a number

Tags: bash, shell, case, wildcard

Good evening,
I want to write a script that will say if its argument is a number or not, however I get this:

```
a: 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")
```

At first I tried like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    case "$1" in
        0x* ) echo hex ;;
        ''|*[!0-9]*) echo dec ;;
        * ) echo wtf ;;
    esac
```

Later I have found this bit:

```
    if ! [[ "$yournumber" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
       exec >&2; echo "error: Not a number"; exit 1
    fi
```

Well, none of them works, I call for help!

Comment: What is the output of `echo ${SHELL}` and `${SHELL} --version`?  The code does not error as stated for GNU bash, version 3.2.19, for one.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Just running this in your interactive shell won't necessarily tell you what is processing the script.  Put the `echo ${SHELL}` line *inside* the script (near the top), and see what output you get.  Also see the comments in [my answer, below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13273733/1072112).

Comment: the output remains the same - bin/bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by `*[!0-9]*`, but the following seems to work for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

case "$1" in
    '')
        echo missing ;;
    0x+([0-9a-fA-F]))
        echo hex ;;
    +([0-9]))
        echo dec ;;
    *)
        echo wtf ;;
esac
```

Note that `extglob` lets me use the more complex pattern match to find "hex" and "dec" numbers.  You can find info on this in the [bash man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash&manpath=FreeBSD+Ports).

Comment: I've tried this way too, but the result keeps the same. now i get :
    a: 3: a: shopt: not found
    a: 8: a: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")
well, i thought its something with my machine, but i just tried it on remote terminal, but nothing changed so far..

Comment: Can you put these results [into your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13273621/edit)?  It's very hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Are you sure you're using bash?  `shopt` wouldn't be found if you were using old-fashioned Bourne shell.

Comment: well, how do i know? i wrote #!/bin/bash at the first line

Comment: How are you running the script?  If it's something like `sh -c scriptname`, then the `#!` part is being treated as a comment, and the script will be parsed by `sh`.

Comment: but anyway, echo ${SHELL} says it's bash

Comment: you're right, it works! with ./file parameters , how does it happens so if eho ${SHELL} said it's bash?

Comment: I *did* say that, in earlier comments.  Per the bash [man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash&manpath=FreeBSD+Ports#INVOCATION) and [other documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), if you're on a system that uses `bash` as its `sh` (i.e. with a symlink or hard link), bash will go into POSIX compatibility mode if it's invoked with the name `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this as a base;

`expr >>/dev/null  "$i" : '0[xX][0-9a-fA-f][0-9a-fA-F]$' && echo hex;
expr >>/dev/null  "$i" : '0[0-7]$' && echo oct;
expr >>/dev/null  "$i" : '[0-9][0-9]*$' && echo dec;`